# WordPress .htaccess redirect with files in a subfolder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am going to try to explain this as best as possible.
I have a WordPress installation at
`www.Domain.com/careers/`.

Which is great, and really not a problem. The main problem is, I'm moving some content over and I'm trying to keep the same URL structure so I don't have to do all the URL ReDirects.

When the site visits a "POST", the URL goes to.
*I have removed the BASE category in the URL, so my URLs would be like.*

```
http://www.example.com/careers/[post-title]

http://www.example.com/careers/[category-title]  << GOOD
```

But what I need to setup now is, when they click on a SINGLE POST, it goes to a URL like this.

```
http://www.example.com/article/[post-title]  << What I need on single-post
```

How do I accomplish that?

**FOLDER STRUCTURE**

```
/Root (APP)

/Root/careers/ *(careers === wordpress install, wp-content...etc)*
```

The HTACCESS For /careers/ IS

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /careers/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /careers/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```